# How achieve similar preciseness in Cloud Vision API detection as Google Lens?

Tags: image-recognition, google-cloud-vision

I would like to detect different plants via Cloud Vision API. I have previously admired the preciseness of Google Lens when detecting plants, but when I try the same thing via Cloud Vision API, I do not get nearly as neat results. It gets the plant family and gives some wrong labels as the most ambiguous results (less than 60% topicality).

Am I missing some step or is it even possible to get results with similar precision with Cloud Vision API? Are there any other (non-Google?) APIs around?

Google Lens detects white dead-nettle as first result:
[image: Google Lens detects white dead-nettle as first result]

Cloud Vision API gets the nettle family correct, and offers some wrong plants:
[image: Cloud Vision API gets the nettle family correct, and offers some wrong plants]

I have tried to find API that would give me similar results as Google Lens, and all answers seem to point to Cloud Vision API, yet it isn't nearly as precise.

Comment: I'm also searching for an answer to the same question. Have you figured out an answer already?